# How to disable button on page load in lightning component

Tags: javascript, lightning

I have 2 buttons "prev" and "next" I want prev button to be disabled on page load in lightning component.
I tried by setting attribute and making it true in init function but doesn't work.

```
<aura:attribute name="hasNext" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:attribute name="hasPrev" type="boolean" default="false"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<ui:button aura:id="buttonPrev" buttonTitle="Prev" class="button"  label="Prev" press="{!c.prev}" disabled="{!hasPrev}"/>
<ui:button aura:id="buttonNext" buttonTitle="Next" class="button" label="Next" press="{!c.next}" disabled="{!hasNext}"/>
```

In javascript controller I have added code to make hasPrev true

```
 doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
            var prevVar = false;
            var nextVar = false;
            console.log('log 1'+component.get('v.hasPrev'););
            component.set("v.hasPrev", true);
            console.log('log 2'+component.get('v.hasPrev'))
}
```

;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you pretty much had it right. All you were missing was the `v.`s in the disabled attribute values.

component

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:attribute name="hasNext" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="hasPrev" type="boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <ui:button aura:id="buttonPrev" buttonTitle="Prev" class="button" label="Prev" press="{!c.prev}" disabled="{!v.hasPrev}"/>
    <ui:button aura:id="buttonNext" buttonTitle="Next" class="button" label="Next" press="{!c.next}" disabled="{!v.hasNext}"/>
</aura:component>
```

controller (unchanged)

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var prevVar = false;
    var nextVar = false;
    console.log('log 1'+component.get('v.hasPrev'));
    component.set("v.hasPrev", true);
    console.log('log 2'+component.get('v.hasPrev'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: check which button you have to display in  that attribute default value make it as true

step2:

Use tag like this :

```
     <aura:if isTrue="{!v.hasNext}">
       //Display which button you want to display
     </aura:if>
```

disable button put in the set [its like else condition ]. It will help you to resolve your Issue

check the Lightning Documention :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_conditional.htm